# Error in Displaying a popover with clickable button on Fullcalendar event click?

Tags: angular, events, fullcalendar, popover, ng-bootstrap

I want to display a pop over on the event click of latest fullcalendar implemented in angular. I tried to call the popover on eventMount and event click callbacks. But both of them are throwing error like "element.popover is not a function" or ".popover of undefined" . Please find the code below:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
               info.element.popover({
                html:true,
                title:"title"
                content:"some content"
                trigger:'click',
                placement:'top',
                container:'body'
            }).popover();
            return false;            
        },
```

But it is throwing error. so i tried to add it in the eventdidmount callback. There also it is showing error like .popover is not a function..

```
 $(info.el).popover({
                    title: title,
                    placement:'top',
                    trigger : 'hover',
                    content: "some content"
                    container:'body'
                }).popover('show');
```

I am new to fullcalendar and angular , Please reply if understood the mistake.

Comment: `Am I missing any libraries or modules in .ts file`...how should we know? We can't see any of your files. But popovers are not a standard part of fullCalendar. You would need maybe popper.js / tooltip.js, or bootstrap. I dunno...depends which popover library you want to use. It's your choice!

Comment: P.S. `eventClick: function(element) {` is incorrect. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick - you get an info object and the element is just one property within it - e.g. `eventClick: function(info) { info.el.popover({...`

Comment: Yes, the event click has info parameter with element inside. sorry , i typed by mistake as element. I tried with info.element. But it is showing error like info.element.popover is not a function.I have edited the post .@ADyson

Comment: Sure. But you still need to include a suitable popover library, and then check its documentation for how you use it. It's not built into fullCalendar

Comment: I am using the bootstrap module for popover. but it is showing error. i imported bootstrap ngb module in ts file . but still the .popover() is throwing error. So without a data-toggle butoon in html, how to initialize the popover from ts file is my doubt.. thats why i asked so.. @ADyson

Comment: Bootstrap popovers require jQuery I think. There should be examples in the bootstrap documentation

Comment: i have imported jquery also in the ts file. but still the error was there. it is always showing the same error like  JQUERY_wEBPACK_IMPORTED module[0] . popover is not a function

Comment: We need to see a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e. enough code and config to be able to see what's going wrong. It's impossible without knowing precisely what, how and and where you've imported things. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example